# How to detect if a Qt GUI application has been idle, inside the app itself (Qt)?

Tags: qt

How to detect when a GUI application has been idle, (ie, no user interaction), for a period of time ?

I have n number of Qt Screens , I want to bring Date-Time screen when application is idle for 5 seconds and when i click on Date-Time screen it should return back to the last screen.

Currently I am using below code, now how to check if system is idle for 5 seconds bring a new form and when some body mousemove/click it should go back to the last form.

```
CustomEventFilter::CustomEventFilter(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{   
    m_timer.setInterval(5000);
    connect(&m_timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(ResetTimer()));
}

bool CustomEventFilter::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *ev)
{
    if(ev->type() == QEvent::KeyPress ||
           ev->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
    {
        ResetTimer();
        return QObject::eventFilter(obj, ev);

     }
    else
    {

    }
}

bool CustomEventFilter::ResetTimer()
{
    m_timer.stop(); // reset timer

}
```

And my main.cpp looks like this :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainForm w;
    w.show();
    CustomEventFilter filter;
    a.installEventFilter(&filter);

    return a.exec();


}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem with showing/closing a form?

Comment: You need to be more constructive in your questions/feedback, not just "give me the code plz" and "does not work, help?". We can't do all your work, nor are we smart enough to figure out what works and what doesn't unless you learn how to provide more info about your problem..

Comment: @Macke : Thank you Macke. I will keep in mind next time while asking questions in SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override [QCoreApplication::notify](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qcoreapplication.html#notify) and a timer on mouse/keyboard events?

(Or just store the time of the event and have a timer check that value periodically, which might be faster than resetting a timer all the time.)

```
class QMyApplication : public QApplication
{
public:
    QTimer m_timer;

    QMyApplication() {
        m_timer.setInterval(5000);
        connect(&m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(app_idle_for_five_secs());
        m_timer.start();
    }
slots:
    bool app_idle_for_five_secs() {
        m_timer.stop();
        // ...
    }
protected:
    bool QMyApplication::notify ( QObject * receiver, QEvent * event )
    {
        if (event->type == QEvent::MouseMove || event->type == QEvent::KeyPress) {
             m_timer.stop(); // reset timer
             m_timer.start();
        }    
        return QApplicaiton::notify(receiver, event);
    }
};
```

Comment: @user662285: Added. Maybe not efficient or complete, but it should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: @Macke : What code I need to write to detect system is idle for 5 seconds then show my datetime screen ?

Comment: @user662285: I've added some sample code to detect idle for 5 seconds. The datetime screen should be trivial, unless you're running stuff in different processes (various options exist, but you need to define your goal more clearly here), or don't know Qt well enough. (fix the latter by doing some tutorials). This is not a site that gives you the code without some thought from you. Please think about your problem, divide into solvable subproblems, attack each and ask for detailed help. Try to avoid "large scope" questions.

Comment: @Macke : I have ellaborated my code above as suggested by you.But that code is not detecting system is idle for 5 seconds.My requirement is when i run my App and if i dont do anything for 5 seconds datetime screen( i already have that) should come.

Comment: @user: You need to start the timer (I added that now). Does that not work? Have you tried debugging (using printf inside the event handler) to see what happens? Also, see OrcunC's comment that you need to stop/start the timer in the handler, not just stop it. Starting is essential. I just stop/start it to make sure it triggers 5 secs from stop/start interval.

Comment: I will not recommend you to override QApplicatioin , instead override your QWidget. Take a look at [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#event) .

Answer (score 5):

According to [QT Documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qcoreapplication.html#exec) :

> To make your application perform idle
>   processing (i.e. executing a special
>   function whenever there are no pending
>   events), use a QTimer with 0 timeout.
>   More advanced idle processing schemes
>   can be achieved using processEvents().

So you need to create a QTimer with zero timeout interval and connect it to your slot that is called when application is idle.

Comment: About you code : It seems that you are just stopping the timer in ResetTimer() method but you are not restarting it !
Macke's code seems correct but it is probably very inefficient to stop and restart a timer at every single mouse and keyboard event ! On top of that at the very first idle slot call he is also stopping the timer and not restarting it or does not care about getting continuous idle events. So his code is also not perfect in my opinion.

Comment: @OrunC : Can you help on this ?

Comment: @Orcunc: No, it's not perfect, but I don't think we get anywhere if we strive for perfect here. ;) Updating a time-of-last-event value and running a 5 sec timer that checks this value (and resets itself with suitable timing, say 3 sec if last event was 2 sec ago) is probably most efficient in terms of computing power.

Comment: Do something like this : QTimer t;//Define this in your header         //connect it your slot in your cpp file
connect(t, SIGNAL(timeout()), h, SLOT(idleCallback()));
t.start(0);//Start timer for idle processing

Comment: @OrunC : This flow is ok. m_timer.setInterval(5000);
    connect(&m_timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(ResetTimer()));
    m_timer.start(0); in my reset timer i should show my Date time form ?