# emit SIGNAL when GUI Thread is idle in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I have *GUI* Thread which creates & manages the *GUI* content. Now when the application is idle i.e. all threads are idle (or even if only the GUI thread is idle) then I want my `QMainWindow` inherited class's object to emit a `SIGNAL`. So that whenever the Application is idle I will silently create the `Widgets` required for the next stage. So I would like to know how do I make that object to emit a `SIGNAL` whenever the *GUI* Thread is idle? My Application is *multi-threaded* & has multiple classes, so it is not necessary that the `SIGNAL` is emitted in the *GUI* class only.
Also the `SIGNAL` should not be emitted as soon as the thread becomes idle. I want that the thread should be idle for a sufficient amount of time so that I am sure that the user is actually idling.
Thank You!

Comment: See this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6534069/667266

Answer (score 14, accepted):

QAbstractEventDispatcher allows one to plug their own events into [Qt's event loop](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qcoreapplication.html#the-event-loop-and-event-handling). Also it allows to monitor event loop's workload.

Here is an example. The widget is listening for QAbstractEventDispatcher::awake() and QAbstractEventDispatcher::aboutToBlock() signals to know when event loop is busy.

```
#include <QtGui>

class IdleAwareWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    IdleAwareWidget(QWidget *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent) {
        dispatcher = QAbstractEventDispatcher::instance();
        connect(dispatcher, SIGNAL(awake()), SLOT(awake()));
        connect(dispatcher, SIGNAL(aboutToBlock()), SLOT(aboutToBlock()));
    }

private slots:
    void awake() {
        lastAwake = QTime::currentTime();
        qDebug() << "Slept for " << lastBlock.msecsTo(lastAwake) << " msec";
    }

    void aboutToBlock() {
        lastBlock = QTime::currentTime();
        qDebug() << "Worked for " << lastAwake.msecsTo(lastBlock) << " msec";
    }

private:
    QAbstractEventDispatcher *dispatcher;
    QTime lastAwake;
    QTime lastBlock;
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QtGui>

#include "idle_widget.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    IdleWidget widget;
    widget.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

If the question is just about idle processing, then QTimer with 0 interval is an option:

```
QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(doWorkInIdle()));
```

This will schedule call to `doWorkInIdle()` slot as soon as the event loop goes to idle state. Splitting work to small chucks won't block the loop and application will remain responsive.