# Is it possible to connect to QApplication notify signal?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I've seen example of `QApplication::notify` usage here: [How to detect if a Qt GUI application has been idle, inside the app itself (Qt)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532490/how-to-detect-if-a-qt-gui-application-has-been-idle-inside-the-app-itself-qt/6534069#6534069)

I need to do the same without basing `QApplication` method. `qApp` has `connectNotify` method so I suppose it should be possible just to make own action on `notify` signal.

If that is possible I need basic example how can I connect to this event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should have a look at event filters, which you can install for all QObjects: [QObject::installEventFilter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter).

Write your own class, which you inherit from QObject and implement the `eventFilter` method, where you insert your event processing logic.
Then install an object of this class to your `QApplication` instance (`qApp` for example)